# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on DELL Inspiron 15R 5520

Tags: windows, dell, laptop, compatibility, inspiron

My laptop is DELL Inspiron 15R 5520 with Windows 7 Ultimate installed and i want to migrate from Windows 7 to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS but first i want to know if my laptop is fully compatible with this version of Ubuntu in terms of drivers, updates, software etc. I also would like to know, from your experience, what are the expected bugs/errors that might come up while using this version of Ubuntu on old systems like this.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: 2012 isn't really that old for a computer. I have a 2012 Dell PC which works fine on 18.04. If your specs are the same as [this](https://www.laptopmag.com/reviews/laptops/dell-inspiron-15r), 6GB DDR3 RAM, Intel Core i5-3210M CPU, there should not be a problem.